# What is the difference between Liferay CE and Liferay EE?

Tags: java, liferay

I am looking for the technical differences between Community Edition and Enterprise Edition.

1. If I develop something for the CE, will it work on the EE?
2. If I create a `LAR` file from the CE, can I import it in the EE?
3. Basically, can I work and develop on the CE and deploy the result on the EE without major problems?

I'm using 6.0.6 CE and EE.

Bonus points for pointing to resources that justify or details the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Liferay has an [overview page](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/overview) of what the differences are. Looks like it boils down to support and tooling.

Comment: Are you referring to actual Admin interface features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.If I develop something for the CE, will it work on the EE?

Yes. Ideally it should work (but then we are not in an Ideal world :-)) so I would say in most cases it does when you are developing custom portlets. Since the API is more or less same.

I say for custom portlets, but I would not say this for hooks. Since I have seen differences in JSPs between CE and EE, like:

- EE uses some `jsp-tag` which is not to be found in CE (this is for version 6.1, for 6.0 I didn't find anything like this).
- also some `*Util` classes in `portal-impl.jar` have extra methods which are used in the JSPs or `Action` classes.

> 2.If I create a LAR file from the CE, can I import it in the EE?

This works. I have tried this with a single site with 20 odd pages. But again caution is required as to what options you set while you export/import. <sub>I would try to update with some examples if possible of the differences</sub>

> 3.Basically, can I work and develop on the CE and deploy the result on the EE without major problems?

Liferay EE's plugins SDK and CE's plugins SDK are different. For the version 6.0 it works deploying CE WAR on a EE server. For 6.1+ have not tried.

you said: "without major problems", for the version 6.0.6 yes it would work without major problems (please take into account explanation to point-1 as well).

Comment: I faced a version mismatch error when trying to import a lar file from Liferay 6.2 CE GA2 to Liferay EE SP6. I guess the imports don't work in 6.2 CE to EE

Answer (score 2):

if you use CE, so you can't use Liferay Developer Studio and have to use EE.
for CE you can use Liferay IDE (eclipse plug-in)